# how to make this code more compact and easy to read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to create all possible combinations of 5 letters, and assign them to variables with the same name:

```
import string
table = string.ascii_letters
table = list(table)
for i in table:
    exec("%s = '%s'" % (i,i))
    for t in table:
        exec("%s = '%s'" % (i+t,i+t))
        for k in table:
            exec("%s = '%s'" % (i+t+k,i+t+k))
            for m in table:
                exec("%s = '%s'" % (i+t+k+m,i+t+k+m))
                for h in table:
                    exec("%s = '%s'" % (i+t+k+m+h,i+t+k+m+h))
```

But it is very big and not to easy to read. How do I make this more compact?

Comment: This tries to set a variable `as` to the string `'as'`. That is not possible, because `as` is a reserved keyword. Can you describe what your actual goal is?

Comment: yeah this is what i have typed for now. in the one that i started in i have try: except: in it

Comment: Can each `for` loop be moved into its own function? There would be 5 `for` loop functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the code review site of the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import string
table = string.ascii_letters
result = list(itertools.combinations(table, 5))
```

Consider that it is a huge list, so maybe you only need the lower or upper case letters instead of all of them:

```
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

list(itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, 5))
```

For creating the variables you can update [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#locals), but I think you should use a dictionary instead, because by creating the variables how would you know if the exist or not?:

```
combination_dict = {"".join(e):''.join(e) for e in itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, 5)}
```

In case you still want the variable behaviour update globals for example:

```
globals().update(combination_dict)
print(cejst)
cejest
```

Comment: Note that this will not find "aaaaa" or any other with repetitions.

Comment: this is not what i mean i mean that they are also in variables stored like that code do's

Comment: This begs the question: Why?

Comment: for an project.

Comment: Can pretty much guarantee that you are better off with a dictionary like @Netwave suggests

Answer (score -1):

```
import string
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for i in combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters,2):
    print("".join(i))
```

Comment: this is not what i mean i mean that they are also in variables stored like that code do's

Comment: Replace the `print` by what you had: `exec("%s = '%s'" % (x,x))`. Or properly create variables by doing `locals()[x] = x` (where `x = "".join(i)`).